# How to model a 1:M relationship in EF without using the dependent's primary key as the foreign key?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-6

I have three entities A, B, and C.  The property MarketAccountNumber on entity C needs to be accessible through entity A.
The entities are as follows:

```
Partial Public Class A
    <Key>
    <Column("CoID", Order:=0)>
    Public Property CompanyId As Byte
    
    <Key>
    <Column("BNum", Order:=1)>
    Public Property B_Number as Integer
    
    Public Property ID as String
    
    <ForeignKey("CompanyID, ID")>
    Public Overridable Property B As B  

End Class
```

```
Partial Public Class B
    <Key>
    <Column("CoID", Order:=0)>
    Public Property CompanyId As Byte
    
    <Key>
    <Column("BNum", Order:=1)>
    <StringLength(15)>
    Public Property Code As String

End Class
```

```
Partial Public Class C
    <Key>
    Public Property C_Id as Integer
    
    Public Property B_Code as String
    
    Public Property MarketAccountNumber

End Class
```

The B_Code field on class C corresponds to Code on class B.

I would like to be able to modify class B as follows:

```
Partial Public Class B
    <Key>
    <Column("CoID", Order:=0)>
    Public Property CompanyId As Byte
    
    <Key>
    <Column("BNum", Order:=1)>
    <StringLength(15)>
    Public Property Code As String

    <ForeignKey(?????)>
    Public Overridable Property C as ICollection(Of C)

End Class
```

Then I could write `A.B.C.MarketAccountNumber` to get the data, but I am not sure what to put for the foreign key in that relationship.  I'm open to any suggestion that would allow me to achieve the goal.

Comment: Little lost what you're asking here.  Why not on class B use C.D_ID for the foreign key?  Is there any need for D_ID.  Honestly, it if I'm following the logic (And I admit I could have this around the wrong way), it's like there is a 1:M between B & C which means B would have a list of C making the navigation property your after not work.   Possibly you might need to review your DB structure some

Comment: Maybe could you give as your intended relationship diagram?

Comment: @Hursey, you are getting the right idea, it is a 1:M relationship.  The problem is that I need class B to reference class C by C.B_Code, and not C.D_ID (edited to C_Id).  multiple Cs can have the same B_Code which is C_Id is necessary.

Comment: A foreign key MUST be unique in the parent table. Based on what you have presented, property `Code` is not unique in class `B` and thus cannot be the parent column in a foreign key.